# How to create bandwidth usage aggregation for each user in kibana

Tags: kibana

I want to create a plot/table of each user bandwidth usage. How do i do it in kibana? I have sent byte and receieved bytes for each user.

In short i want the output of

```
   select users, sum(sentbyte + receievedbyte) from TABLE_NAME group by users order by users desc
```

Kibana : [image]

**Updated question :**

Today, I came to know there is no support of aggregation in kibana 3.X version. You have to use kibana 4.x. I have used the following form of request to elastic search and it gives the desired result. But how i do i represent it in the graphical form in kibana 4 beta 2?

```
POST logstash-2014.12.02/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_bandwidth": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "order": {
          "TotalBandwidth": "desc"
        }
      },
       "aggs": {
        "TotalBandwidth": {
          "sum": {
            "script" : "doc['rcvdbyte'].value + doc['sentbyte'].value"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would accomplish this in the latest build of the Kibana 4 Beta (master):

1. Setup a scripted field for the users total bandwidth. For now, I've called this field `bandwidth`, use the script `doc['rcvdbyte'].value + doc['sentbyte'].value`, and set the return value to `Number`
   [image: scripted field editor]
2. Use a sum aggregation to add up the `bandwidth` for each user. In my dataset I don't have users, so I'm using `clientip`.
   [image]

While my data is slightly different, the fields could be swapped out for your dataset and should work just fine. These aggregations should also work in other visualization types.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I couldn't find the option to add scripted field in Kibana 4 beta 2.

Comment: The scripted fields feature is only available in master at the moment. It will be released in Beta 3 soon.