# how to get the total value of field in kibana 4.x

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I need to get the total value of field in **Kibana** using **script field**.

e.g) if **id** field have values like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

I am looking to `sum` up all the values of id, I am expecting the output is 15.

I need to achieve the below formula after getting total of each field.

```
lifetime=a-b-c-(d-e-f)*g
```

here **a,b,c,d,e,f,g** all are total of the each field values.

for more info please refer this [question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-aggregate-data-like-mysql-query-kibana/67922/1) which is raised by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use sum aggregations to get the sum of id, but to further equate your formula, you can take a look at [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) to use the sum value for further calculations.

Take a look at [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html), with proper bucket path to sum aggregator you can achieve your solution.

For sample documents

```
{
  "a":100,
  "b":200,
  "c":400,
  "d":600
}
```

query

```
 {
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "result": {
         "terms": {"script":"'nice to have it here'"},
         "aggs": {
            "suma": {
                "sum": {
                    "field": "a"
                }
            },
            "sumb": {
                "sum": {
                  "field": "b"
                }
            },
            "sumc": {
                "sum": {
                  "field": "c"
                }
            },
            "equation": {
                "bucket_script": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "suma": "suma",
                        "sumb": "sumb",
                        "sumc" : "sumc"
                    },
                    "script": "suma + sumb + 2*sumc"
                }
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can surely add term filter on each sum agg to filter the summation for each sum aggregator.

Comment: Oh! it's really hard to understand. if you don't mind, can you explain with simple example to reproduce my formula?

Comment: is it not possible to convert elasticsearch aggregation into kibana graph view? http://stackoverflow.com/q/37850262/5528059

Comment: sure, ok i now understand what you are trying to achieve, so a,b,c,d ... are sum of id's computed for different set of documents and you then want to combine them in the formula. give me some time i will try to give you a smaller implementation

Comment: should also thanks to this guy,the one with last comment on the issue for the trick - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14656

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this in your `scripted fields`:

```
doc['id'].value
```

Hence, you could use a `sum` aggregation to get the total value in `Kibana`.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169965/how-to-create-bandwidth-usage-aggregation-for-each-user-in-kibana) could be handy!

**EDIT**

If you're trying to do it using `Elasticsearch`, you could do something like this within your request body:

```
"aggs":{  
         "total":{  
             "sum":{  
                 "script":"doc['id'].value"
             }
          }
      }
```

You could follow up this [ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html#_script_9), but then if you're using `painless` make sure you do include it within `lang`. [related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467211/elastic-search-sum-aggregation-with-group-by-and-where-condition)

Comment: thanks! can you please explain bit more. `doc['id'].value` in kibana it return records for each row not sum of the id field. where should I apply sum aggregation elasticsearch or kibana? may be it is really silly but I don't know:-) please review my updated question

Comment: You can either do it from `ES` side or if it's using `Kibana`, you can use the `sum` aggregation in a graph.

Comment: I think you are not understand my question fully! single field sum aggregation in kibana graph is not a problem for me. could you look at my formula? e.g) if I have seven sum aggregation fields in kibana graph, now how to apply the above mentioned formula to the seven fields?